# What causes EventMachine::ConnectionNotBound?

Tags: ruby, eventmachine

I'm new to EventMachine, so I'm not sure what this means.  I'm getting this exception:

```
EventMachine::ConnectionNotBound recieved ConnectionUnbound for an unknown signature: ef93a97d4d6441cb80d30fe2313d7de73
```

The program is fairly complicated, so I can't really explain everything that might have led up to it.  All I need is a pointer towards what to look for.  The error doesn't seem to be documented (looking at http://eventmachine.rubyforge.org/).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have had this exception raised when some other unhandled exception was raised in the initialize method of a subclass of EventMachine::Connection. Check that the arity of your subclass initialize method is correct and that the initialize method is running without errors.

Answer (score 6):

Usually, those errors occur in initialize or post_init. The first thing you should do is add rescue inside your callbacks to find out what actually is causing that error.

```
def initialize(*args)
  ...
  super
rescue Exception
  ...
end

def post_init
  ...
  super
rescue Exception
  ...
end
```

Comment: This is great advice, and thanks for the illustration, but it doesn't catch Troy's scenario, where the arity of `#initialize` is wrong.  That turned out to be my problem.  (Actually, I was doing the calling, not being the connection.)  Probably a good answer for someone else with the same question, though.  :)

Answer (score 1):

I fixed Exception bubbling for this case in EventMachine over a year ago. It's in the prerelease 1.0 gem (`gem install eventmachine --pre`) or better, use EventMachine from the repository.

Comment: I've seen this comment in several places on this subject. I;m using EventMachine version 1.2.7 and it's still a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue and while investigating came across https://github.com/igrigorik/em-http-request/issues/190#issuecomment-16995528

You basically need to wrap `EM::HttpRequest.new` with `EM.schedule` or `EM.next_tick` if you're making `EM::HttpRequest.new` in your code even though its under a `EM.defer`